# How to set cookies to a login form with knockout js?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to make a login form that uses cookies with knockoutjs. I found a jsfiddle that work for a select box
( http://jsfiddle.net/mikevh/DP3TE/2/ ),

```
<select data-bind="options: options, value:selected, optionsText:'Name'"></select>
<button data-bind="click: save">Save</button>
```

and I tried to modify that and to do it with inputs. Here it is:

https://jsfiddle.net/boa2y2vq/5/

```
<input type="text"  data-bind="value:username"/><br>
<input type="password" data-bind="value:password"/><br>
<button data-bind="click: save">Save</button>
```

But it's not working. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/boa2y2vq/8/

Here is a list of problems:

1. `ko.applyBindings(new vm(options));` was failing because no variable by name `options` was declared.
2. The statements getting the data from cookie were failing when the value was not set in cookie. You can wrap them in a `try..catch` to avoid the issue.
3. In your case you can set the value directly into a cookie using `setCookie('username', self.username());` instead of `setCookie('username', self.username().value);`. Notice that I have omitted the `value` property.

View Model:

```
var vm = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  var username = "";
  var password = "";

  try {
    var cookieUser = parseInt(getCookie('username'));
    var cookiePassword = parseInt(getCookie('password'));
    username = data[cookieUser - 1];
    password = data[cookiePassword - 1];
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error!", e);
  }
  self.username = ko.observable(username);
  self.password = ko.observable(password);
  self.options = ko.observableArray(data);

  self.save = function() {
    setCookie('username', self.username());
    setCookie('password', self.password());
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```